# Unable to install tweepy in python2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, github, tweepy

I've been trying to install tweepy in python so I can begin to make a program that tracks criminal behaviour on twitter, but I can't even get tweepy installed onto python. I've tried looking to sort this problem out, looked at similar problems and solutions and I can't figure out why this isn't working.

I've tried these two commands to install it but I've had no luck. I also tried downloading it off github but it doesn't recognise the 'git' command

```
easy_install tweepy

pip install tweepy
```

I have attached an image of the output of the cmd at the bottom on this question. Is it something I'm doing wrong and/or is there a way around it?

[image]

Comment: Do you have easy_install, pip and git installed on your computer?

Comment: try 'python -m pip install tweepy' and if that fails then try 'sudo pip install tweepy'

Comment: @AK47 Yes, they're in the C:\Python27\Scripts library
The 'python -m pip install tweepy' gives the same output as what is shown on the image and the sudo command isn't recognised. I don't think it is installed

Comment: Try downloading the .whl file from [here](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tweepy/3.5.0) and install using pip?

Comment: @DavidG That is also giving the same error as show on the image that I've attached. Do you think this could be because I'm connected to the network at work as it's saying 'Failed to establish a new connection[Errno 11004]'?

Comment: @OllyR Yes, that might be the reason as I can install tweepy fine on Python 2.7